# Why can't FFmpeg code compile on different ARM 64 bit platforms？

Tags: c, linux, ffmpeg

The same code (test_ffmpeg.c), I have compiled it on the x86_64 platform successfully, and there is no problem. I can successfully push the video to the [RTMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) server. However, if I switch to the ARM 64-bit platform, there is a problem with the compilation. Why?

1. Cross compile x264

   ```
   ./configure --enable-shared --disable-asm
   ```

   Edit *config.mak*

   ```
   SRCPATH=.
   prefix=/usr/local
   exec_prefix=${prefix}
   bindir=${exec_prefix}/bin
   libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
   includedir=${prefix}/include
   SYS_ARCH=aarch64
   SYS=LINUX
   CC=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
   CFLAGS=-Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wshadow -O3 -ffast-math   -Wall -I. -I$(SRCPATH) -std=gnu99 -
   D_GNU_SOURCE  -fPIC -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-tree-vectorize
   COMPILER=GNU
   COMPILER_STYLE=GNU
   DEPMM=-MM -g0
   DEPMT=-MT
   LD=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -o
   LDFLAGS=  -lm -lpthread -ldl
   LIBX264=libx264.a
   AR=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar rc
   RANLIB=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib
   STRIP=strip
   INSTALL=install
   AS=
   ASFLAGS= -I. -I$(SRCPATH)  -f elf64 -DSTACK_ALIGNMENT=64
   -DPIC
   RC=
   RCFLAGS=
   EXE=
   HAVE_GETOPT_LONG=1
   DEVNULL=/dev/null
   PROF_GEN_CC=-fprofile-generate
   PROF_GEN_LD=-fprofile-generate
   PROF_USE_CC=-fprofile-use
   PROF_USE_LD=-fprofile-use
   HAVE_OPENCL=yes
   CC_O=-o $@
   default: cli
   install: install-cli
   SOSUFFIX=so
   SONAME=libx264.so.157
   SOFLAGS=-shared -Wl,-soname,$(SONAME)  -Wl,-Bsymbolic
   default: lib-shared
   install: install-lib-shared
   LDFLAGSCLI = -ldl
   CLI_LIBX264 = $(LIBX264)
   ```

   then,

   ```
   make && make install
   ```
2. Cross compile FFmpeg

   ```
   ./configure --arch=aarch64 --enable-cross-compile --target-os=linux --cc=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc --
    cross-prefix=aarch64-linux-gnu- --prefix=./ffmpeg_result  --enable-shared --disable-static --
    disable-doc  --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib/ --extra-libs=-ldl -
    -extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/include
   ```

   Add output of ffmpeg configure:[output](https://pastebin.com/yNpTQkAa).

   then,

   ```
   make && make install
   ```
3. Cross compile file *test_ffmpeg.c*

   ```
   aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc test_ffmpeg.c  -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavfilter -lavformat -lavutil -L
   /data/ffmpeg-4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib -I /data/ffmpeg-4.3/ffmpeg_result/include -g
   ```

An error occurred, as detailed below:

```
test_ffmpeg.c: In function 'main':
test_ffmpeg.c:63:3: warning: 'codec' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
AVStream *out_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, in_stream->codec->codec);
^~~~~~~~
In file included from test_ffmpeg.c:4:
/data/ffmpeg-4.3/ffmpeg_result/include/libavformat/avformat.h:880:21: note: declared here
AVCodecContext *codec;
^~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning:
libswresample.so.3, needed by /data/ffmpeg-4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavcodec.so, not found (try
using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning:
libswscale.so.5, needed by /data/ffmpeg-4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so, not found (try
using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning:
libpostproc.so.55, needed by /data/ffmpeg-4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so, not found (try
using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to `sws_freeContext@LIBSWSCALE_5'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to `pp_get_context@LIBPOSTPROC_55'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to `swr_alloc_set_opts@LIBSWRESAMPLE_3'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to `pp_postprocess@LIBPOSTPROC_55'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to `swr_get_class@LIBSWRESAMPLE_3'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to `sws_scaleVec@LIBSWSCALE_5'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to
`swr_set_channel_mapping@LIBSWRESAMPLE_3'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to `sws_getCoefficients@LIBSWSCALE_5'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavcodec.so: undefined reference to `swr_alloc@LIBSWRESAMPLE_3'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to `sws_getGaussianVec@LIBSWSCALE_5'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to
`pp_get_mode_by_name_and_quality@LIBPOSTPROC_55'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to `swr_next_pts@LIBSWRESAMPLE_3'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavcodec.so: undefined reference to `swr_init@LIBSWRESAMPLE_3'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to
`sws_setColorspaceDetails@LIBSWSCALE_5'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to `sws_isSupportedOutput@LIBSWSCALE_5'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to `sws_init_context@LIBSWSCALE_5'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavcodec.so: undefined reference to `swr_close@LIBSWRESAMPLE_3'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to `sws_alloc_context@LIBSWSCALE_5'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to `sws_scale@LIBSWSCALE_5'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to `swr_get_delay@LIBSWRESAMPLE_3'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to `pp_free_context@LIBPOSTPROC_55'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavcodec.so: undefined reference to `swr_convert@LIBSWRESAMPLE_3'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to `sws_freeVec@LIBSWSCALE_5'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavcodec.so: undefined reference to `swr_is_initialized@LIBSWRESAMPLE_3'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to `sws_getContext@LIBSWSCALE_5'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to `pp_free_mode@LIBPOSTPROC_55'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to `sws_isSupportedInput@LIBSWSCALE_5'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to `sws_getCachedContext@LIBSWSCALE_5'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to `swr_set_matrix@LIBSWRESAMPLE_3'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to `sws_get_class@LIBSWSCALE_5'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavcodec.so: undefined reference to `swr_free@LIBSWRESAMPLE_3'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to
`sws_getColorspaceDetails@LIBSWSCALE_5'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /data/ffmpeg-
4.3/ffmpeg_result/lib/libavfilter.so: undefined reference to
`sws_isSupportedEndiannessConversion@LIBSWSCALE_5'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I still see a `-DARCH_X86_64=1` in the makefile

Comment: @ user3386109  According to what you said, I deleted it, but it is still the same.

Comment: That was just the first thing I saw. Here's the second thing I see: `-I$(SRCPATH)/common/x86/`. If you're going to cross-compile, you need to look at every line of that makefile, and get every line right. And that's just the beginning of the journey. Best of luck.

Comment: The linker is complaining about not finding libswscale, libswresample and libpostproc. Add the full output of ffmpeg configure to your Q.

Comment: @Gyan the output of ffmpeg configure a little bit large, which exceeds the limit of stack overflow.I choose a part to add.

Comment: Upload it to someplace like pastebin and link it.

Comment: @ Gyan thank you, I have added it.

Comment: @user3386109 you are right, I add --host=aarch64-linux  to cross-compile x264, but an error in https://pastebin.com/WhvCY1fd, can you help me ?

Comment: solve it by adding  -lswscale -lpostproc.                                                    
##aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc test_ffmpeg.c   -L /data/ffmpeg_result/lib/ -I /data/ffmpeg_result/include/ -g -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavfilter -lavformat -lavutil -lswresample -lswscale -lpostproc -pthread -lz

Comment: If you solved it you can add the solution as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by adding options *-lswscale* and *-lpostproc*.

Cross compile file *test_ffmpeg.c*:

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc test_ffmpeg.c -L /data/ffmpeg_result/lib/ -I 
/data/ffmpeg_result/include/ -g -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavfilter -lavformat 
-lavutil -lswresample -lswscale -lpostproc -pthread -lz.
```

But why don't I need to add these two options on the x86_64 platform when compiling?